# Custom Product Template breaks options in Bigcommerce Stencil

Tags: bigcommerce

After creating and assigning a custom product page template to one of my items, the JavaScript for this page breaks. The JS removes a display:none style on the product options container. Any idea why this would happen?

Comment: What theme and version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Cornerstone version 1.8.2

Comment: Try updating to 1.9.1 which should have a fix for that issue.